# Chart.js add icons like <i class='icon-peso'></i> to y-axis labels

Tags: javascript, php, html, chart.js

I have these currency classes for `<i> </i>` tags e.g. `".icon-peso"`.
How do I format the y-axis in chart.js to show these `<i class="icon-peso"> </i>` tags?

Also these classes use a custom font that I've uploaded into http://app.fontastic.me/

What I need is to show it like this: `P100,00.00`.

Here's my code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var barLabel = <?php echo json_encode($ch3_arrDate); ?>;
    var dataVal1 = <?php echo json_encode($ch3_arrRevenue_conf); ?>;
    var dataVal2 = <?php echo json_encode($ch3_arrRevenue_tent); ?>;

    var dateFilter = <?php echo json_encode($ch3_arrDate2); ?>;

    var barData = {
        labels: barLabel,
        datasets: [
            {
                label: 'Confirmed Revenue',
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(163,216,3,0.5)',
                data: dataVal1,
            },
            {
                label: 'Tentative Revenue',
                backgroundColor: 'rgba(28,83,130,0.5)',
                data: dataVal2,
            },
        ]
    };

    var barOptions = { 
        responsive: true,
        maintainAspectRatio: true,
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    beginAtZero: true,
                    userCallback: function(value, index, values) {
                        return addCommas(value.toFixed(2));
                    }
                }
            }]
        },
        legend: {
            display: true,
            position: 'bottom'
        },
        tooltips: {
          callbacks: {
            label: function(tooltipItem, data) {
              return addCommas(tooltipItem.yLabel.toFixed(2));
            }
          }
        }
    }


    var ctx = document.getElementById("chart3").getContext("2d");
    ctx.canvas.height = 300;

    var chartDisplay = new Chart(ctx, {
        type: 'line',
        data: barData,
        options: barOptions
    });

    $("#chart3").click( 
       function(e){
            var activeBars = chartDisplay.getElementsAtEvent(e);
            var index = activeBars[0]["_index"];
            location.href="dash_chartdeals.php?from=future&filter_date="+fixedEncodeURIComponent(dateFilter[index]);
    });

    $("#chart3").mouseenter(function(){
        $("#chart3").css("cursor", "pointer");
    });
});
```

Comment: Update this **var dateFilter** with this **var dateFilter= '<?php echo json_encode($ch3_arrDate2) ?>';** and try.

Answer (score 0):

Update your exist variables with below and try.

```
var barLabel = '<?php echo json_encode($ch3_arrDate) ?>';
var dataVal1 = '<?php echo json_encode($ch3_arrRevenue_conf) ?>';
var dataVal2 = '<?php echo json_encode($ch3_arrRevenue_tent) ?>';
var dateFilter = '<?php echo json_encode($ch3_arrDate2) ?>';
```